# How do I display user input using HTML and PHP using an array

Tags: php, html, arrays, post

So I want to have the user input an animal into the array and it display back using the PHP function. I know I am missing some code, but what else do I need?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Proj. 2</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1> Animal Form</h1>

        <form action="display.php" method="post">
            Enter animal:<br>
            <input type="text" name="animal"><br><br>
            <input type="Submit" value="Add Animal">
        </form>

        <?php
        function display()  {
            $animal = $_POST['animal'];//If code doesnt work change these variables
            echo $_POST["animal"];
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't appear to be **invoking** the function `display()`.

Comment: Also, the line "$animal = $_POST['animal'];" is redundant and not necessary if all you're wanting to do is display the user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function display() hasn't been called. Just call it

```
<?php
    display();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your function, if `$_POST['animal']` is set, actually you created function but didn't call it to print the value,

```
if(isset($_POST['animal'])){
    display();
}
```